# javafx treetableview column size

Tags: java, javafx-2, treetableview

I'm developing a java fx application and I'm using a TreeTableView, and when I insert some data inside it , it looks like this : [image]

Is there a way , so I can make the columns stretch in order to view all the content inside the cell?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [#setPrefWidth](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#setPrefWidth-double-) method from `TreeTableColumn` class to set preferred width for columns.
As shown in [this example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/tree-table-view.htm#CJAEIFDC).

Comment: what if the prefwidth is smaller than the content inside the cells?